# MariaDB on Windows 11 Pro fails due to privilege tables' file problems

Tags: windows, mariadb, xampp

About 5-6 days after *each* fresh installation of (the newest) XAMPP 8.2.4 on Windows 11 Pro (10.0.22621 Build 22621), MariaDB 10.4.28 on-board it starts to fail during every run:

Sometimes I am getting an error directly in XAMPP:

```shell
Attempting to start MySQL app...
Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
```

I am a total newbie, but I think there isn't anything "unusual" in *mysql_error.log*:

```
[Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 20488
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
[Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
[Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
[Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
[Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
[Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
[Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 1972203; transaction id 2830
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

But the Windows Event Log has seriously puzzling entries.

For each run I am getting either only this:

```
Aborting
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'db'
```

Or the above followed by:

```
mysqld.exe: Aria engine: checkpoint failed
mysqld.exe: Can't sync file 'C:\XAMPP\mysql\data\aria_log.00000001' to disk (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")
mysqld.exe: Error writing file 'C:\XAMPP\mysql\data\aria_log.00000001' (Errcode: 9 "Bad file descriptor")
```

The "Bad file descriptor" is something that rings the "broken disk" bell in my head, but Windows say no:

[image]

```
(...)
0 bad file records processed.
Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 1.61 milliseconds.
(...)
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
```

I tried the "idiot" way of simply deleting the *aria_log.00000001*. All I achieved was:

- *One* time startup of MariaDB
- Adding extra line to log that *aria_log.00000001* was not found
- Creating and using *aria_log.00000002*, *aria_log.00000003* etc.

But that was just a "virtual" run. All the clients could see that MariaDB is running (XAMPP having `Status change detected: running` as the last log line and no error), but in fact it was some kind of a weird "lock" that clients cannot detect this fact and hangs without timeout forever:

[image]

The same goes for browsers, which shows "circling circle" forever, until I manually kill db.

After that everything goes back to "normal" meaning `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.` on each and every run.

I haven't tried the "bruteforce mode" ([here](https://serverfault.com/a/813123/127070)). When the serie of "unexpected shutdowns" starts, I am simply:

- Uninstalling XAMPP (backing up data)
- Deleting the whole *C:\XAMPP* folder
- Doing fresh-install of XAMPP 8.2.4

After this, I am always "good for the next couple of days". Usually five to six.

I've been using XAMPP for Windows for 10+ years, on Windows versions starting XP and never experienced any problems. Until now.

Is there anything that I can do, except for getting rid of XAMPP forever and trying some other LAMP (since re-install doesn't bring anything)?

**EDIT**: *There was no update neither to Maria DB nor the whole server-like system (Apache/XAMPP). Everything sticks on XAMPP 8.2.4 and MariaDB 10.4.28**strong text** for at least half of year. The only "updates" are my constant sequences of uninstall-install back (did so right now).*

**EDIT**: *This is Windows 11 Pro (10.0.22621 Build 22621), so underlying storage system is a single SSD drive (KBG50ZNS512G NVMe KIOXIA 512 GB; 475 GB true capacity). This is a brand new laptop, so the disk has been running for 2,5 weeks so far.*

Comment: "Bad file descriptor"? Tell us about the storage system used for the database.

Comment: Was this an upgrade from an older version of MariaDB?  Which version?

Comment: Thank you both for trying to help. Answered by editing the question. No update to MariaDB for past 6+ months and single SSD NVMe disk as storage system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may consider one of the following solutions.

#### Data Backup

Various reports ([here](https://buildio.dev/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/) and [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=83059)) suggests that the solution might be:

1. Navigate to XAMPP MariaDB directory (*c:\xampp\mysql*)
2. Create some backup folder like *DataBackup* (just in case)
3. Copy contents of *backup* and *data* folders into *DataBackup* folder
4. Copy an overwrite all contents of *data* folder with contents of *backup* folder
5. Copy the *ibdata1* file from *DataBackup\data* folder into *data* overwriting the file
6. Try to restart MySQL.

Many users [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=83059) has reported that the above solutions works. I did not tried it.

#### File Fixing

By a total accident, I have found a file in *mysql\bin* folder called *[username].err* where *[username]* is your Windows username. Its contents showed what was (see below) the true nature of the problem:

```
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5dd7)
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

And also has suggested the possible solution:

```
[ERROR] mysqld: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
```

I did not tried this solution as well.

#### Database Server Upgrade

Instead of trying any of these two methods I simply updated my MariaDB database version to the newest one.

This solution required me to [do some magic on my MariaDB users](https://onezeronull.com/2023/10/23/authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client/) because newest MariaDB server is using different authentication method (GSSAPI plugin) instead of the old version (native MySQL authentication).

Unfortunately this solution also was working for just a 2-3 days and after that [MariaDB started crashing with exactly the same behavior](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/332439/35230), in exactly the same circumstances and without any chances to recover.

#### Run it as a Windows System Service

While reading some more threads, I have figured out someone claiming that "*all those *nix-services works more stable when running as a system service in Windows*".

I don't know how much truth there is in this claim, but since XAMPP allows that easily, I have given this solution a try:

[image]

This solution seems to be working (at least for now).

#### Last resort. No stop or pseudo-backup

If the above solution starts failing as all others then the last chance for me is an old-dirty trick of simply not stopping MariaDB at all and hibernating may dev PC instead of turning it off.

Sounds crazy, but as one of my friends has proven... works.

All reports (linked here and all those that I have read) says that problems with MariaDB starts on first or second shutdown. So... let's not let her take even a inch of sleep! :]

Another "stupid" and "hardcore" solution is to compress entire XAMPP installation when MariaDB still works and then "recreate" it back to that stage, whenever it stops working. Something a bit similar to "hardcore data overwrite" mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/332439/35230).

For me fortunately this is just a dev laptop where I don't give a damn what data database contains as long as it works. This solution isn't of course for all these scenarios where data is important and cannot be simply overwritten or rolled back couple of days.

Comment: Congratulations for your perseverance.  Wishing you many trouble free days with this resolution.  If you need us, we will try to assist.

Comment: There is some confusion around GSSAPI in the article your quote.  nobody changed default authentication in 11.2 . User root is using it _as fallback_ on Windows if mysql_native_authentication does not work, and that's it.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub When I have reinstalled 11.2 over 10.4.28, I had to recreate my data from backup (as my DBs were empty). Did so. I started my app and it immediately started to throw exceptions about inability to authenticate in DB. The same message appeared in phpMyAdmin. Only then I have realized that both "out-of-the-box" users (root) and my imported ones are using GSSSAPI authentication method. Switching back to native resolved issue in my app and in phpMyAdmin. That's all that I know. I don't know what, when and in which circumstances has changed authentication method for these users.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to repair the privilege table
`mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p`

Comment: My entire question is about the fact that I cannot **start** MariaDB server. How can your answer help me, if it requires MariaDB server to **be already started**? Executing your command ends with: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`.